# Getting nginx-ingress to use UDP in Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

Currently this setup worked for TCP but once switched to UDP I get the error

```
The Service "nginx-ingress-controller" is invalid: spec.ports: Invalid value:
 []core.ServicePort{core.ServicePort{Name:"proxied-udp-30001", Protocol:"UDP",
 Port:30001, TargetPort:intstr.IntOrString{Type:0, IntVal:30001, StrVal:""}, 
NodePort:0}, core.ServicePort{Name:"proxied-udp-30002", Protocol:"UDP", 
Port:30002, TargetPort:intstr.IntOrString{Type:0, IntVal:30002, StrVal:""}, 
NodePort:0}, core.ServicePort{Name:"http", Protocol:"TCP", Port:80, 
TargetPort:intstr.IntOrString{Type:1, IntVal:0, StrVal:"http"}, NodePort:32724},
 core.ServicePort{Name:"https", Protocol:"TCP", Port:443, 
TargetPort:intstr.IntOrString{Type:1, IntVal:0, StrVal:"https"}, 
NodePort:30127}}: cannot create an external load balancer with mix protocols
```

Right after I tried to apply the patch

```sh
kubectl patch deployment nginx-ingress-controller -n ingress-nginx --patch $(Get-Content .\k8s\prod-azure-multi-pod-node\nginx-ingress-controller-deploy-patch.yaml -Raw)

kubectl patch svc nginx-ingress-controller -n ingress-nginx --patch $(Get-Content .\k8s\prod-azure-multi-pod-node\nginx-ingress-controller-svc-patch.yaml -Raw)
```

Where each of these files are

nginx-ingress-controller-svc-patch.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: nginx-ingress
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/services/nginx-ingress-controller
spec:
  ports:
  - name: proxied-udp-30001
    port: 30001
    targetPort: 30001
    protocol: UDP
  - name: proxied-udp-30002
    port: 30002
    targetPort: 30002
    protocol: UDP
```

And nginx-ingress-controller-deploy-patch.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/deployments/nginx-ingress-controller
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true # Edit added via tutorial https://skryvets.com/blog/2019/04/09/exposing-tcp-and-udp-services-via-ingress-on-minikube/
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=ingress-nginx/nginx-ingress-default-backend
        - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
        - --ingress-class=nginx
        - --udp-services-configmap=default/udp-services # Needed for udp config map usage
        - --configmap=ingress-nginx/nginx-ingress-controller
        name: nginx-ingress-controller
```

The services look like so

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: game-svc-1
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    instance: game-1
  # type: NodePort
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 9001 # exposed port
      targetPort: 19132
```

And the Udp config file

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: udp-services
  namespace: default
data:
  30001: "default/game-svc-1:9001"
  30002: "default/game-svc-2:9002"
```

Like I said this works perfectly fine when using tcp but once I switched to UDP that error pops up, is there a UDP step I am missing?

EDIT > add helm command as stated by microsoft to use [this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic#create-an-ingress-controller)

```sh
helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --namespace ingress-nginx --set controller.replicaCount=2 --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set controller.service.httpPort.enable=false --set controller.service.httpsPort.enable=false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based to the following error:

```
The Service "nginx-ingress-controller" is invalid: spec.ports: Invalid value:
 []core.ServicePort
{core.ServicePort{Name:"proxied-udp-30001", Protocol:"UDP", Port:30001, TargetPort:intstr.IntOrString {Type:0, IntVal:30001, StrVal:""}, NodePort:0}, 

core.ServicePort{Name:"proxied-udp-30002", Protocol:"UDP", 
Port:30002, TargetPort:intstr.IntOrString{Type:0, IntVal:30002, StrVal:""}, 
NodePort:0}, 

core.ServicePort{Name:"http", Protocol:"TCP", Port:80, 
TargetPort:intstr.IntOrString{Type:1, IntVal:0, StrVal:"http"}, NodePort:32724},

core.ServicePort{Name:"https", Protocol:"TCP", Port:443, 
TargetPort:intstr.IntOrString{Type:1, IntVal:0, StrVal:"https"}, 
NodePort:30127}}:
```

The Error tell you exactly that you are trying to update the service with a mix match in PORT type.

`cannot create an external load balancer with mix protocols`

This is because the PATCH command will augment the existing service with the added configuration.(in your case 2 new exposed UDP port) on top of the existing configuration (2 TCP port)

The best way to convert from TCP to UDP would be to reuse the name port names (`http` and `https`) this will allow the PATCH command to merge the dictionary entries together, replacing the TCP and pour 80/443 with your UDP port settings.

If you are actually looking at supporting both UDP/TCP, you will need to change the ServiceType to `ClusterIP` since the `LoadBalancer` type doesn't support having a mismatch of protocol for a single Public IP (Azure LoadBalancer FrontEnd IP)

Comment: It looks like I still get the same error, I even tried to apply an entire new service on top and it gives me an error that those names already exist.

Comment: you will need to share your initial service.yaml and deployment.yaml

Comment: you will need to disable the TCP from the service using the helm chart. this is possible using

Comment: ```
controller.service.enableHttp if port 80 should be opened for service true
controller.service.enableHttps if port 443 should be opened for service true
```                                                                                                       
controller.service.enableHttp=false
controller.service.enableHttps=false

Comment: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-service.yaml#L49

Comment: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-service.yaml#L58

Comment: Must be a bug then, those commands don't do anything to get rid of the http and https ports. I will post an issue on github.

Comment: please share the helm command and the value.yaml you are using. this will help

Comment: Added the command and the reference to where I was told to use those parameters.

Comment: --set controller.service.enableHttp=false

--set controller.service.enableHttps=false

Comment: use those arguments instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213803/discussion-between-mjwrazor-and-djsly).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, it looks like patch is not able to correctly merge the manifest files since that is evident from TCP port being mentioned in error which is missing from manifest file shared. 
Can you try applying the manifest file directly instead of using patch?

Comment: The main manifest is created when installing nginx-ingress from helm. Its a pretty large yaml file, it also includes TCP prots for http 80 and https 443 which I can't seem to get rid of.

Comment: Check the parameters controller.service.enableHttp and controller.service.enableHttps from helm nginx-ingress (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress). If you disable these values, it should not appear in the manifest generated.

If you are still getting those port, please provide the parameters which you are using to deploy nginx-ingress.

Comment: In the chat we used these commands `--set controller.service.enableHttp=false --set controller.service.enableHttps=false` as well as `--set  udp.30000="default/service:30000"` it should work but would suggest using a values.yaml. 

Like so
`helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress -n ingress-nginx -f values.yaml` Thanks though